# how to pass an optional parameter along with required parameters in Web methods in Vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, optional-parameters

There is a web method. We have 2 parameters. We need to pass the third parameter as optional parameter to a web service in vb.net framework 2.0 Visual studio 2005.What are the ways to give the parameter as a optional parameter?

Comment: There is no way to do optional parameters in web services. That's a platform-specific feature, and web services are platform-neutral.

Comment: Can you overload the method?

Answer (score 0):

2 choices:

1. Always overload if you can, much clearer and simpler
2. Call a function that adds the third parameter as "" or 0 if it only has two parameters (depending if string or double or else)

What I mean (or something similar, just wrote it quickly):

```
dim threeParameter = addThirdParameter({FirstParameter,SecondParameter[,thirdParameter]})
myWebMethod(threeParameter(0),threeParameter(1),threeParameter(2))

private function addThirdParameter(_input() as string)
    dim _output(2) as string 'or double or w/e
    if ubound(_input) = 1 then
        _output(0) = _input(0)
        _output(1) = _input(1)
        '_output(2) = ""
        return _output
    else 'Already has 3 parameters
        return _input
    end if
end function
```

This snippet should check if you entered 2 or 3 parameters, if you entered 2, it adds an empty parameter (""), if you entered 3 it returns the input.

Hope it helps